# python: Indentation Error: expected an indented block

Tags: python

I try to get data from twitter by using API and tweepy python.
After install successfully python and tweepy, a try to get data..
Here is my code

```
enter code here
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
ckey = 'YIlpVeuTTqjJhWbFj6kmF2ecL'
csecret ='rDUpUgmJF6ZVFYsKGbLW43JXoX35mTzQW7JoPWCQwUh2sBhEaM' 
atoken = '3262955994-MwFta8wXh0mjIXatX12BL5Smw2ABZtomMLD782E'
asecret='hcyYCOuBBEsrq3MtBpwI2IQqAqIj4wHpCH0rAODR9C6g6'
class listener(StreamListener):
def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken,asecret)
twitterStream= Stream(auth,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])
```

When I run it, i had an error:

```
file 'ex.py' ,line 10
   print data
       ^
 IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I got this code on the Internet.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using uneven indentation, I can see 8 spaces in these lines -

```
def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True
```

where as only 4 in line -

```
def on_error(self, status):
    print status
```

I am guessing you have more code where you are using 4 spaces for one level of indentation.

You should use constant amount of spaces for indentation throughout your code. I would advice you to try changing the indentation of the function to 4 spaces and check if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you indented twice on that line.  Instead indent `on_data()` the same way as it is done for `on_error()` (that is, 4 spaces for one level of indentation).